# React perf always prints empty Array

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs, performance-testing

I'm trying to test the performance of my app by using react perf tools. The problem is its not working.
I call

```
Perf.start()

Perf.stop()

Perf.printWasted()
```

in the console, which works (no console errors or warnings), but `printWasted()` always returns empty Array and a message

> Total time: 0.00 ms

This also happens for other functions like `printInclusive()` and `printExclusive()`
What can be the problem?
P.S I'm using react-router, how is react perf performing with that? Maybe that's causing some issues?
Also, `process.env.NODE_ENV` is not set to production, and I'm using `React 0.13.3`

Comment: maybe it's a stupid question, but you're not by any chance running them one after another, right?

Comment: @Hatsuney What do you mean by 'them' and 'one after another' :)? If you mean start() and stop() methods, I run start, then perform some actions that cause the app to re-render, then call stop() at some point, and after stop() i call printWasted().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having the same problem as described here - in my case it was a silly mistake, though. It's possible that you (or someone else in the future) may have made the same silly mistake, so I thought I'd explain what I did.

I was writing some test code where I loaded the React library directly into the page -

```
<script src="/Script/ThirdParty/react-15.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="/Script/ThirdParty/react-dom-15.0.0.js"></script>
```

When I wanted to get information about how the page was performing, I also loaded the "addons" script -

```
<script src="/Script/ThirdParty/react-15.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="/Script/ThirdParty/react-dom-15.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="/Script/ThirdParty/react-with-addons-15.0.0.js"></script>
```

Then refreshed the page, went to the console and typed

```
React.addons.Perf.start()
```

I interacted with the page so that a re-render occurred and then typed

```
React.addons.Perf.stop()
React.addons.Perf.printWasted()
```

and I always got

> Array[0]
>
> Total time: 0.0ms

The mistake was that the addons script should not be loaded *in addition* to the primary React script, it should be loaded *instead* - ie.

```
<script src="/Script/ThirdParty/react-with-addons-15.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="/Script/ThirdParty/react-dom-15.0.0.js"></script>
```

After correcting that, I started getting results from the perf tool methods.

Comment: Actually this was the same solution that worked for me. I forgot to update this thread. Thank you for sharing this solution, even though I should have done it!

Comment: This also helped me a ton! I bundle my app into a `vendor` and `main` package using Browserify, and because I failed to include both `react` and `react-addons-perf` in the vendor package, they ended up not sharing code and not working.

Answer (score 1):

I've stumbled upon the same problem when using [webpack's extarnals](https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html) as suggested in this quickstart: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html

```
// webpack.conf.js:
//...
externals: {
    "react": "React",
    "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
}
```

with

```
// index.js
// ...
window.Perf = require('react-addons-perf')
```

and

```
// index.html
<script src="/js/react/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="/js/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bundle.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

Turns out this configuration also causes `Perf` results to always be empty. Removing `externals` entry (and thus putting react inside the webpack's bundle) solved the problem. Turns out there was no build time performance difference.